# Accessing relative path in Python

Tags: python, path

I'm running a Mac OS X environment and am used to using ~/ to provide the access to the current user's directory.

For example, in my python script I'm just trying to use

```
os.chdir("/Users/aaron/Desktop/testdir/")
```

But would like to use

```
os.chdir("~/Desktop/testdir/")
```

I'm getting a no such file or directory error when trying to run this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to use [`os.path.expanduser(path)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path#os.path.expanduser)

`os.chdir("~/Desktop/testdir/")` is looking for a directory named "~" in the current working directory.

Also pay attention to the documentation of that function - specifically that you'll need the `$HOME` environment variable set properly to ensure that the expansion takes place.  Most of the time this wont be a problem but if the expansion doesn't take place, that's the likely reason.

Comment: I didn't know about that one! +1

Comment: Very cool, how do I actually use this properly? Is the "path" supposed to be "/Desktop/testdir"? And how do I actually change to that directory. Thanks so much.

Comment: Just nest it inside your existing chdir call like so: os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/..."))

Comment: That was much easier than I was trying to make it. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 4):

From http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

```
os.path.expanduser(path)
```

Will expand ~ to being the users home directory if it is defined.

Comment: I tried os.path.expanduser("/Desktop/testdir") and it is telling me no such file or directory: '/Desktop/test/' Do you know what I might be doing wrong? Ultimately I would like to chdir to ~/Desktop/testdir

Comment: os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/testdir") is what you would need, as Dan Head mentioned, this relies on $HOME being set.